# Cannot connect to localhost on Chrome when using VSCode

Tags: html, google-chrome, localhost

Just written a HTML document using VSCode. When i run via Chrome it opens a window on localhost:8080, but says that the site cannot be reached. 'Refused to connect'

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Usually use Notepad++ which i realise is so much more straightforward than VSCode.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please write a better question. In order to do so, please click on the link. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you want a server to open a html page

Comment: Vscode or notepad has got nothing to do with HTML and Chrome and a server and also localhost. For now, you can try live-server extension on vscode for a quick way to view HTML via localhost. Please watch some basic tutorials on youtube which explain HTML, basic servers, localhost, vscode setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can just click on the file and it will run automatically.
[image]

Comment: You can tick it so people see that it is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your launch.json file. Then,run'ng serve' command in angular cli. VSCode will show your localhost and you should press it to run the project.
If the problem go on, clear chrome cookies.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31896852)

Comment: The problem is that when it runs the project it doesn't connect to localhost on Chrome. Is it right? I had this problem. And when I made changes to the project, I solved the localhost binding by executing the ' ng serve' code. You can do that. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need localhost to view an HTML page, just find the HTML on your desktop or documents or where ever you created it, right click on the file and open it with a browser of your choice

You can then edit the file in VSCode or Notepad++ or any text editor of your liking, then go back to the browser and reload the page to see the changes to your file